# Unable to update the Listview and notifyDataSetChanged() also not working with SeekBar

Tags: android, android-listview, android-seekbar

Implemented ListView and loading first set of data the Listview, based on the seekBar onProgressChanged next values should be updated. Tried with notifyDataSetChanged() and all the solution in stack but not working. Or else how can I make Listview refresh after loading the second set data instead, any solution apart from notifyDataSetChange because just need to change the only some part of values.

SeekBar Code

````
@Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {

        String number = jsonDates.get(progress);
        System.out.println("number:"+number);

        // Date dateObj = dateFormat.parse(number);

        if(oldIndex != progress){

            transFunction();

            ```customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();```

            oldIndex = progress;

        }

        // selectedTxtFld.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
````

Function (Api call snippet)

```
public Void transFunction(){

 RequestQueue reqQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            reqQueue.add(new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Log.d(TAG, response);
                    if (response != null){
                        try {
                            System.out.println("We are in JsonObject");
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            System.out.println("Got Json Object"+jsonObject);

                           // Arrays.fill(nameString, null);
                            absValuesArray.clear();
                            diffValuesArray.clear();
                            currValArray.clear();
                            prevValArray.clear();
                            jsonDates.clear();
                            indData.clear();

       ListView listView = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
                            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

}
```

Custom Adapter

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return nameString.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);

//            ImageView

            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E1E1E1F0"));
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            }


            System.out.println("nameString_lenth"+nameString.length);
            System.out.println("currArrayObject"+currArrayObject.length);
            System.out.println("diffArrayObject"+diffArrayObject.length);

            TextView textView_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            TextView textView_current = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
            TextView textView_difference = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview3);
            ImageView transImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.transimage);


            textView_name.setText(nameString[i]);
            textView_current.setText(currArrayObject[i]);
            textView_difference.setText(diffArrayObject[i]);
            //transImageView.setImage =


            return view;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following problems:

1) you shouldn´t set the adapter to the `ListView` everytime your `transFunction` method is called. You need to set the adapter once. Preferable when you initialize your `ListView`.

2) your `Adapter` implementation isn´t correct. You don´t return an item and you don´t return an itemId. You should do something like this:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position); 
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

This [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView) shows an example, how to use a ListView with a BaseAdapter.